# How can you join the survival server on Mineplex?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried playing on Super Fun Time a little bit, which seems to be a very user-friendly, beginner-friendly server, but I'm concerned about the number of players on it.  Mineplex seems a lot more appealing, but I don't seem to be able to join any of its servers.  I am able to join its lobby, which has several different portals pointing to different servers; but if I go to one of those portals, nothing happens.  I see other players running to those portals, one after another, and joining either the survival server or some other server; but whether I try the survival one or any other one, nothing happens.

If Mineplex's site has a contact page, it's concealed.  There are also no instructions in the handbook Minecraft item about how to talk in chat on Mineplex.  I would just give up on such a server, but it looks like it may be worth getting into, if only this one particular issue would get out of the way.

How can you join the survival server?  You should be able to run into the portal in the lobby server, it seems, but that's not working for me.  Is there at least some way to seek technical support about that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking on one of the mobs named the name of the game in front of the portals. This will bring up a list of servers. Emerald blocks represent games that haven't started, gold blocks represent games that have started. Click on one of the emerald blocks to join a waiting lobby.